# Sqoop 1.99.3, export into MySQL returns empty tables

Tags: mysql, datetime, export, hdfs, sqoop

**Original question**

I am working with Sqoop 1.99.3 and I am trying to export a file from HDFS to MySql, that contains a DateTime field. Unfortunately, after the job is executed, the target table is empty, and there are no error messages/logs.

- Does this version of Sqoop
  support the DateTime format?
- Is there a workaround for this problem?

An example of csv row:

- 1,'name',2016-04-01 15:10:57,2016-05-31 05:00:59

Create statement for the MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `unit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `u_save_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_save_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Since I was asked to, here is my code. Nothing revolutionary, copied from Sqoop 5-minute demo Client Api guide ([link](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/ClientAPI.html)) with modified parameters (here I pasted their default ones).

**The code works just fine for the tables that do not contain datetime format. I also tried exporting through sqoop shell (with same parameters) but the target tables were, again, empty**

Code in Java :

```
String url = "http://localhost:12000/sqoop/";
SqoopClient client = new SqoopClient(url);
MJob newjob = client.newJob(1, org.apache.sqoop.model.MJob.Type.EXPORT);
MJobForms connectorForm = newjob.getConnectorPart();
MJobForms frameworkForm = newjob.getFrameworkPart();

newjob.setName("ExportJob");
connectorForm.getStringInput("table.schemaName").setValue("");
connectorForm.getStringInput("table.tableName").setValue("table");
connectorForm.getStringInput("table.columns").setValue("id,name");

frameworkForm.getStringInput("input.inputDirectory").setValue("/input");

frameworkForm.getIntegerInput("throttling.extractors").setValue(1);
frameworkForm.getIntegerInput("throttling.loaders").setValue(1);

Status status = client.createJob(newjob);
if(status.canProceed()) {
  System.out.println("New Job ID: "+ newjob.getPersistenceId());
} else {
  System.out.println("Check for status and forms error ");
}

printMessage(newjob.getConnectorPart().getForms());
printMessage(newjob.getFrameworkPart().getForms());
```

---

**Follow-up question**

Okay, I've managed to resolve this problem. However, now I am facing the same problem with a different table (even with DateTime being properly formatted).

An example of csv row:

- 1,'name','name','2016-05-11
  12:08:27','3a99471d-6f42-445f-b651-4a557a0e5b97'

The last column is Java generated UUID and is stored as char(36).

Comment: Also sqoop export command

Comment: I've added my code and some explanation. As I've written in the post, there is no error/exception in the sqoop log file. And thank you for wanting to help! :)

Comment: @devツ I figured out the problem with this file. The datetime field should be enclosed by ' '. My bad. However, another file returns an empty table even with single quotations around datetime fields and the error log is empty. I will add more details in the post.

Comment: I tried with Sqoop 1.4.6. It worked there perfectly without quotes. I am not much familiar with sqoop 2. Good to know that you solved it...!

Comment: @devツ yup, I have 1.4.6 working perfectly, but trying to migrate to sqoop2... do you perhaps know if a csv file needs to have an id of int auto_increment type in order to be exported into mysql? thanks!

Comment: I have not tried it. But sqoop export will simply make `insert into table...` statements. Now sqoop will not exclude id column _(auto_increment)_ from the `insert into...` statement. so, you will get an error in sqoop export. Either add id in csv file or add `--columns <all remaining columns comma separated>` in your sqoop export command.

Comment: @devツ I see... thank you so much. Unfortunately that is an option that is available in sqoop 1.4.6, not the version I'm trying. So I either need to use that version for export or try to find a way to do it in this version... which is proving to be a giant hassle...

Answer (score 1):

**I've figured out the problem with datetime fields. Datetime should be enclosed by single quotations(''), f. e:**

- 1,'name','2016-04-01 15:10:57','2016-05-31 05:00:59'